# Making a discord bot able to handle several inputs at once

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This is a pretty basic question but here is the issue. I am trying to make a discord bot that takes a message and delays it by a set amount of time. However, it only can handle one message at a time and will not delay any others until that one has gone through. Is there a way to make it so the bot can handle all the messages at once?
here is the code for the function

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.author.bot:
        await message.delete()
        time.sleep(100)
        await message.channel.send('{} : {}'.format(message.author.name,
                                                    message.content))
        await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: maybe this [docs.python/sched](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html) package is what you are looking for

Comment: Oh, that will probably do the trick, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `time.sleep()` blocks code and pretty much stops everything from working until the time set expires. What you want to use is `asyncio.sleep()`

```py
import asyncio

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.author.bot:
        await message.delete()
        await asyncio.sleep(100)
        await message.channel.send('{} : {}'.format(message.author.name,
                                                    message.content))
        await client.process_commands(message)
```

`asyncio.sleep()` will still allow you to do what you intended to do but also allow the bot to continue working and accept more requests/tasks.

Comment: thank you so much. After fighting with Sched for long enough, I am pretty sure it will not work for what I need to do just based on how the two plugins are designed. This, however, will